# Save external Tweets in database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, rails-activerecord

I am new to rails developement and to the MVC architecture. I have a little application where I can add Videos' URLs from Dailymotion or Youtube and get the tweets related to that URL using the twitter gem in Ruby on Rails.

Now i'm able to store the tweets like this : (This is the video controller)

```
 def show
  @video = Video.find(params[:id])

  # Creating a URL variable 
  url = @video.url

  # Search tweets for the given video/url
  @search = get_client.search("#{@video.url} -rt")

  # Save tweets in database
  @search.collect do |t|
    tweet = Tweet.create do |u|
    u.from_user =  t.user.screen_name.to_s
    u.from_user_id_str = t.id.to_s
    u.profile_image_url = t.user.profile_image_url.to_s
    u.text = t.text.to_s
    u.twitter_created_at = t.created_at.to_s
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it (doing it in the controller ?), and what I want to do now is to specify that those tweets that have just been stored belong to the current video. Also I would like to have some sort of validation that makes the controller look in the database before doing this to only save the new tweets. Can someone help me with that ?

My models :

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :url
   has_many :tweets
end

class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :video
end
```

My routes.rb

```
 resources :videos do
  resources :tweets
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a "fat controller", an antipattern in any MVC architecture ([here's a good read on the topic](http://joncairns.com/2013/04/fat-model-skinny-controller-is-a-load-of-rubbish/)).

Have you considered introducing a few new objects to encapsulate this behavior? For example, I might do something like this:

```
# app/models/twitter_search.rb
class TwitterSearch
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def results
    get_client.search("#{@url} -rt")
  end
end

# app/models/twitter_persistence.rb
class TwitterPersistence
  def self.persist(results)
    results.map do |result|
      self.new(result).persist
    end
  end

  def initialize(result)
    @result = result
  end

  def persist
    Tweet.find_or_create_by(remote_id: id) do |tweet|
      tweet.from_user =  screen_name
      tweet.from_user_id_str = from_user_id
      tweet.profile_image_url = profile_image_url
      tweet.text = text
      tweet.twitter_created_at = created_at
    end
  end

  private

  attr_reader :result

  delegate :screen_name, :profile_image_url, to: :user
  delegate :id, :user, :from_user_id, :text, :created_at, to: :result
end
```

Notice the use of `find_or_create_by` ... Twitter results should have a unique identifier that you can use to guarantee that you don't create duplicates. This means you'll need a `remote_id` or something on your tweets table, and of course I just guessed at the attribute name (`id`) that the service you're using will return.

Then, in your controller:

```
# app/controllers/videos_controller.rb
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @tweets = TwitterPersistence.persist(search.results)
  end

  private

  def search
    @search ||= TwitterSearch.new(video.url)
  end

  def video
    @video ||= Video.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Also note that I've removed calls to `to_s` ... ActiveRecord should automatically convert attributes to the correct types before saving them to the database.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great answer, very complete. Thanks !

Comment: I got an error on line 13 of Twitter_persistence.rb : "can't cast Addressable::URI to string". What does it mean ? I changed my `remote_id` type to bigint because Tweets ids are as long as 434042964382580740. But I'm not sure this worked because console shows me integer type for `remote_id`.

Comment: Hard to tell what's causing the error without seeing a stack trace, but if I had to guess, I'd start looking to see if it has anything to do with the return value of `video.url` (seems reasonable that it might return an instance of `Addressable::URI`), and how it interacts when you call `get_client.search("#{@url} -rt")` ... as for the column type, that's just how Integers work in Ruby. [Here's a good read on the topic](http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/1/9/how-big-is-a-bignum).